# How to attach label to dendrogram in Python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have difficulty in labeling a dendrogram, I keep having error message each time I try.
here is my code:
 `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline`

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 50))  
plt.title("Dendrograms")  
dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(df, method='ward'), leaf_font_size=12, orientation='right', labels=Country)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-2310a4d5ca2d> in <module>
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(20, 50))
      3 plt.title("Dendrograms")
----> 4 dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(df, method='ward'), leaf_font_size=12, orientation='right', labels='Country')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py in linkage(y, method, metric, optimal_ordering)
   1040         raise ValueError("Invalid method: {0}".format(method))
   1041 
-> 1042     y = _convert_to_double(np.asarray(y, order='c'))
   1043 
   1044     if y.ndim == 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py in _convert_to_double(X)
   1562 def _convert_to_double(X):
   1563     if X.dtype != np.double:
-> 1564         X = X.astype(np.double)
   1565     if not X.flags.contiguous:
   1566         X = X.copy()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'USA'
```

There are 12 features in the **df** and I want to label the dendrogram using **Country** names. But if I drop **Country** without specifying **labels** it will plot using **0, 1, 2,...,n** in instead of the country names since it was not specified. But if I specify the **labels** and include **Country** in the df I have the above error. How do I go about it please

Answer (score 1):

This question is already a few months old, but doesn't have an answer yet. So I will give one.

For the solution I expect that `Country` is a column in your `df` DataFrame. The `label` option of the `dendogram` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) doesn't expect a column of your actual data `df`, but a seqence/list/array like structure. To get your code working you just have to drop the `Country` column and, pass the rest to the `linkage` function and set the `Country` column seperately.

A fix for your example with the column `Country` named "country" would be to replace the `dendogram` line by the following:

```
shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(df.drop("country", axis=1), method='ward'), leaf_font_size=12, orientation='right', labels=df["country"])
```